# Passing map to common procedure

Tags: ada

The Java programming languages frequently uses interfaces like `java.util.Map`.

In the following example two custom map packages are created by using the generic packages `Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps` and `Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps`. Both generic packages are offering the functions/procedures `Clear` and `Length`. The procedures `Do_Something` are using this functions/procedures to clear the passed map and to print the container length (stupid example ...).

I am right then it is not possible to create a procedure `Do_Something_Special` that would accept maps of both types `Map_One.Map` and `Map_Two.Map`? In Java it would be possible to define a parameter with the type `Map<Natural, Unbounded_String>`.

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps;
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   function Hash (Value : Natural) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
   begin
      return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type (Value);
   end Hash;

   package Map_One is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps
     (Key_Type        => Natural,
      Element_Type    => Unbounded_String,
      Hash            => Hash,
      Equivalent_Keys => "=");

   package Map_Two is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => Natural,
      Element_Type => Unbounded_String);

   procedure Do_Something (Input : in out Map_One.Map) is
   begin
      Input.Clear;

      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Length: " & Input.Length'Image);
   end Do_Something;

   procedure Do_Something (Input : in out Map_Two.Map) is
   begin
      Input.Clear;

      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Length: " & Input.Length'Image);
   end Do_Something;

   procedure Do_Something_Special (Input : in out ???) is
   begin
      Input.Clear;

      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Length: " & Input.Length'Image);
   end Do_Something_Special;
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Comment: Through the magic of overloading you already have most of what you want in `Do_Something`, except you have code duplication. To eliminate that, I'd do something like the first generic in Jere's answer, except I'd call the generic procedure something else, and name the instances `Do_Something_Special` (giving the instances different names doesn't achieve the desired result). Using interfaces and type extension is less clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like in Java you can use generics or interfaces.

A generic only solution:

```ada
generic
    type Map is private;
    with procedure Clear(Self : in out Map);
    with function Length(Self : Map) return Ada.Containers.Count_Type;
procedure Do_Something_Special(Input : in out Map);
procedure Do_Something_Special(Input : in out Map) is
begin
    Clear(Input);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Length: " & Length(Input)'Image);
end Do_Something_Special;

procedure Do_Something_Map_One is new Do_Something_Special
    (Map    => Map_One.Map,
     Clear  => Map_One.Clear,
     Length => Map_One.Length);

procedure Do_Something_Map_Two is new Do_Something_Special
    (Map    => Map_Two.Map,
     Clear  => Map_Two.Clear,
     Length => Map_Two.Length);
```

If instead you want to go the route of using a Map interface you can do the following:

Create a generic interface for any key/value types

```ada
use Ada.Containers;

generic
    type Key_Type is private;
    type Element_Type is private;
package Map_Interfaces is

    type Map_Interface is interface;
    procedure Clear(Self : in out Map_Interface) is abstract;
    function Length(Self : Map_Interface) return Count_Type is abstract;

    -- other operations

end Map_Interfaces;
```

Next implement it for the key/value types you want:

```ada
package My_Map_Interfaces is new Map_Interfaces
    (Key_Type     => Natural,
     Element_Type => Unbounded_String);

use My_Map_Interfaces;
```

Now you are able to use the class type of the interface to operate on any map that implements that interface:

```ada
procedure Do_Something_Special_1(Input : in out Map_Interface'Class) is
begin
    Input.Clear;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Length: " & Input.Length'Image);
end Do_Something_Special_1;
```

Then you just need to extend the Ada map types and implement the interface:

```ada
type Map_1 is new Map_One.Map and Map_Interface with null record;
type Map_2 is new Map_Two.Map and Map_Interface with null record;

M1 : Map_1;
M2 : Map_2;
```

and you can call it this way:

```ada
Do_Something_Special_1(M1);
Do_Something_Special_1(M2);
```

OR you an create another generic function if you want static dispatch instead of dynamic:

```ada
generic
    type Map is new Map_Interface with private;
procedure Do_Something_Special_2(Input : in out Map);

procedure Do_Something_Special_2(Input : in out Map) is
begin
    Input.Clear;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Length: " & Input.Length'Image);
end Do_Something_Special_2;

procedure Do_Something_Map_1 is new Do_Something_Special_2(Map_1);
procedure Do_Something_Map_2 is new Do_Something_Special_2(Map_2);
```

and call it like this:

```ada
Do_Something_Map_1(M1);
Do_Something_Map_2(M2);
```